# Solidity field size of mapping type

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, evm

Solidity [allows](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html#structs) mapping types inside a struct. How many bytes does such a field cost?

Specifically I'd like to optimise the [storage layout](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/miscellaneous.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage) of the following type.

```
struct Balance {
    uint40 amount;
    mapping(address => uint) allowances;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean the storage layout, not memory layout.

`uint` is an alias for `uint256`, which is 256-bits. So each value stored in that mapping uses one 32-byte slot in storage.

**EDIT**

For the full `Balance` struct, each one will consume two slots in storage, but one slot will always be zero. The first slot is consumed by the `uint40`, and the second is a placeholder for the `mapping` that doesn't actually have any value stored. In terms of gas cost, that's free.

So storing a new `Balance` will write one 32-byte word to storage, and then each `uint` you add to the `allowances` mapping will write one 32-byte word to storage.

Comment: Correct. What I want to know is how many bytes one Balance instance costs. So that'll be 40 + ...?

Comment: If the edit is true then how would the runtime know which allowances belongs to which value in `mapping(address => Balance)`?

Comment: Mappings work by hashing. `foo[bar]` is at the hash of the `bar` concatenated with the storage slot for `foo`. https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/03/09/understanding-ethereum-smart-contract-storage/ may help, or the documentation you linked to.

Comment: So for `mapping(address => Balance) foo`, `foo[a][b]` lives at the slot found by concatenating `b`, `a`, and the slot for `foo`.

Comment: In other words, say we have a `mapping(address = Balance) all` with two entries, say `all[0]` and `all[1]`. If only the `amount` fields are stored then how does the runtime know the difference between entries in `all[0].allowances` and `all[1].allowances`?

Comment: Assuming `all` is at slot `0`, then `all[1].allowances[2]` is at the location `keccak256(2 || (keccak256(1 || 0) + 1))`. In other words, you find the location of `all[1]`, which is a `Balance`, and then you add 1 to get the slot for `all[1].allowances`. Then you concatenate 2 and that slot to get the location for `all[1].allowances[2]`. The slot for `all[2]` is different, so the entire computation is different.